# Submit parent form on clicking radio button in partial with all parameters and not refreshing in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has a partial like this:

**parent_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :questions, url: { controller: 'questions', action: 'update' }, method: :put, authenticity_token: true, html: { id: 'questions_form' }, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'question', :locals => {
      :question => question,
      :answers => question.answers
    } %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :marked_questions_list, '', :id=>'marked_questions_list' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :hidden_field_2, '', :id => 'hidden_field_2' %>

<button id="mark_question">Mark Question</button>

<%= f.submit 'Answer', :class => '', id: 'answer_btn' %>
```

**_question.html.erb**

```
<div><%= question.body %></div>
<table class="choices">
    <% answers.each do |answer| %>
      <tr class="answer_selection">
        <td class="answer_input" data-update-url="<%= update_path %>" id="answer_input">
          <%= radio_button_tag 'question[answer_id]',
                                answer.id,
                                false,
                                {
                                  class: 'answer_option',
                                  # onclick: "this.form.submit();"
                                  onclick: "answerQuestion(#{answer.id});"
                                } %>
        </td>
        <td class="answer_text">
          <%= label_tag 'question[answer_id]',
                        html_safe(answer.body_html) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

**ajax.js**

```
answerQuestion = async (answerId) => {
  let updateUrl = document.getElementById('answer_input').dataset.updateUrl;
  let marked_questions_list_value = document.getElementById('marked_questions_list').value;
  let hidden_field_2_value = document.getElementById('hidden_field_2').value;
  let data = { marked_questions_list: marked_questions_list_value, hidden_field_2: hidden_field_2_value }
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(updateAnswerUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: data,
      headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
    });
    const response = await resp.json();
    if (response.success) {
      document.dispatchEvent(answerEvent);
    } else {
      alert('Oops !!! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Oops !!! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page');
  }
};
```

Here if I click on `answer_btn` in the `parent_form` or if I use `onclick: this.form.submit();` then the form is submitted along with all the required parameters in `hidden_field_tag`. How can I submit the form without refreshing the partial on clicking the radio_button through `updateQuestion` method along with the `hidden_field_tag` and other form parameters? Basically I want the functionality of `answer_btn` or `onclick: this.form.submit();` without refreshing the page on clicking any radio button in partial so that I can remove the `answer_button` from the parent_form completely. Also there another button `Mark Questions` in the `parent_form`. On clicking this button, one of the `hidden_field_tag`s is modified. The values of `hidden_field_tag`s that are sent from parent_form to controller on clicking either of the buttons are changed from javascript. So they are dynamic. So `hidden_field_tag`s should be present when I click the radio buttons in partial or any button in parent_form.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rails nature, it will refresh, however, workaround for what you wanted is

After updating in the controller take a @marked_question_list and store marked question in it. Next store hidden_field_2 values in @hidden_field_2.

Create a update.js.erb
In that

```
$('#marked_questions_list').val(<%=@marked_question_list%>);
$('#hidden_field_2').val(<%=@hidden_field_2%>);
```

If I have understood your question correctly this supposed to solve your problem. Try this and let me know.

Comment: I am already updating the values in js. What I want is to send the values to partial. Right now the workaround is to get the values in partial like this: `let marked_questions_list = document.getElementById('marked_questions_list');`

Comment: @Lax_Sam I need little more light on it! Do you want to send the selected value of the current question to the question partial, which is going to render once the current answer submits? Do you want to keep the selected value in the 'marked_questions_list' which is in the parent_form? If you can enlighten me!

Comment: I am updating the values of `hidden_field_tag`s on any click event. What I want is to send the values of `hidden_field_tag`s to the controller whenever the radio button in the partial is clicked or the button from the parent_form is clicked.

Comment: I have updated the question. This seems to work but is this the correct way?

Comment: @lax_sam if you are sending any request to controller it's has to be through the method.js.erb file to update hidden_field_tag as I said before. Or else if you want all the data to submit at once you can write a jQuery to append the new answer in the hidden_field_tag and make the submit button enable when all answers are filled and submit at once. Both are right approach according to rails standards, but 1st approach is recommended.